# Generate querystring to be used as url for API request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, query-string, react-router-redux

I want to have a query string that can be used for filtering my results.
Whenever the url changes an action will be called using Redux to load my data with the given filters in the URL.

An example url looks as follows:

```
/trainers?filter=city=Antwerp&firstName=Dax&lastName=Bosch&postalCode=2600&page=1
```

With this given URL my `action.payload` should look like this:

```
payload:
  filter: "city=Antwerp&firstName=Dax&lastName=Bosch&postalCode=2600"
  page: 1
  sortField: undefined
  sortOrder: undefined
```

This is how I'm currently making my query string

```
  filterAdvancedSearch = (values: FormikValues) => {
    updateAdvancedSearchQueryString(this.props, {page: 1, filter: this.filterSearchResults(values)});
  };
  filterSearchResults = (values: any) => {
    let obj: any = {};
    Object.keys(values).forEach(
      key => values[key].length && (obj[key] = values[key])
    );
    return obj;
  };
```

I'm passing my props and my object that will be used for generating the query string. `filterSearchResults()` is used for getting rid of empty values

How I make my query string and push it to my route:

```
export function updateAdvancedSearchQueryString<T>(
  props: RouteComponentProps,
  newValues: any
) {
  props.history.push({
    pathname: props.location.pathname,
    search: queryString.stringify(newValues)
  });
}
```

I'm using the [querystring](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html) module from node.js, but because of the fact that I have an object within my filter object,  my url and `action.payload` are looking as following:

```
/trainers?filter=%5Bobject%20Object%5D&page=1

payload:
  filter: "[object Object]"
  page: "1"
  sortField: undefined
  sortOrder: undefined
```

**How can I use the querystring module to make it work on a nested object, or how to do it without using the module?**

Answer (score 0):

Try use `URLSearchParams` class:

```
filterSearchResults = (values: any) => {
    let obj: any = {};
    Object.keys(values).forEach(
      key => values[key].length && (obj[key] = values[key])
    );
    return new URLSearchParams(obj).toString();
  };
```

Comment: This works, but the main problem now is that when I call the querystring method the string from obj gets encoded, would like to keep it decoded to give the user a readable url. The url looks as follows: `/trainers?filter=firstName%3DDaan%26lastName%3DBoschmans%26postalCode%3D2600%26city%3DAntwerpen&page=1`

Comment: You can  not keep it decoded like `filter=city=Antwerp&firstName=Dax&lastName=Bosch&postalCode=2600&page=1` it will mess up the request and `filter` won't have the right data. You may need to remove `filter=` and just have the other params accessible individually like `?city=Antwerp&firstName=Dax&lastName=Bosch&postalCode=2600&page=1`

Comment: That is indeed an option, but my payload is using the filter reference to know the actual search query, if I remove it I would need some other reference that isn't being showed in the url, and I would like to keep page, filter, order,.. Seperate